# How to POST parameters using JSONArrayRequest in Volley - (ERROR string cannot be converted to jsonarray)

Tags: java, android

This question may look like a duplicate(it is NOT), but I am stuck with this JSONException error:

> Value die of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray.

I'm using `JsonArrayRequest` of `Volley` to get jsonarray from a server. My `JsonArrayRequest` is throwing the above error, as i want to `post` a string to the server and receive jsonarray as a response. Below is my code:

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            // Parsing json
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject JO = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    GetterSetter getterSetter = new GetterSetter();

                    getterSetter.setName(JO.getString("name"));
                    getterSetter.setNumber(JO.getString("number"));
                    getterSetter.setDate(JO.getString("date"));

                    myList.add(getterSetter);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("myKey", myValue);

            return params;
        }
    };
    MySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}
```

The PHP file is working properly and it is passing json string to android.

The error is happening somewhere within `onResponse` block. The same block works clean when using `StringRequest` instead of `JsonArrayRequest`.

Any idea what exactly is causing this error? Any help or guidance is much appreciated.
* I'm new in Android Volley  and the way it works.

EDIT

This is a format/syntax of the url response:

```
[
    {"name":"test",
     "number":"123",
     "date":"2017-08-22"
    },
    {"name":"test1",
     "number":"1234",
     "date":"2017-08-23"
    }
]
```

Comment: I think problem related to the response means Your response is string and it accept only JSONArray. check response on Postman or RestClient.

Comment: Post the JSON response.

Comment: try to open the URL from postman, i think PHP response is not a valid JSON, mostly it's an error message contains the word `die` the famous PHP `or die (...)`, plz share the PHP code

Comment: @Dheerubhai Bansal - Checked URL from postman, no problem with the respond. I'm suspecting the parameter of 'onResponse' is returning 'String', while I'm assigning 'JSONArray' to it. Any thoughts in this regard?

Comment: post `response.toString()` here.

Comment: It seems like it's crashing *before* reaching onResume, post the entire stack trace?

Comment: 100% php page returns a string not JSON, the string starts with **die**, that's what the exception says, if it works from postman, then the android code is not sending parameters correctly (may be param name not mykey?) and PHP page crashes because it did not receive expected parameters, that's what i told you earlier, share PHP code it will explain a lot

Comment: @Yazan - PHP code works fine, it never crashed in the process. Android sends String parameter as well. Also, Android gets/receives php response perfectly well. The problem is in Volley - i.e. the way it handles responses. I ended up using `StringRequest` as @Shahin Mursalov suggested, but still is wondering how to use `JsonArrayRequest` to make it work. Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try using StringRequest and then create your own JSONArray from the response string:

```
new JSONArray(response);
```

You can find example StringRequest from the documentation:

[Sending a Simple Request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

Comment: Even though I wanted to use 'JsonArrayRequest', this definitely works as well. Thank you!